# Wordpress theme css : impossible to change navigation position

Tags: css, wordpress, position, themes

I'm working with this free theme : http://demo2.woothemes.com/mystile/

And I would like to change the position (put it on the center) of the main navigation menu. (the one with home, shop ...).

I have traveled through the style.css and layout.css (also tried with firebug) but I can't find where it's indicated that it should be on the right. I guess it's a "float:" ?

The only way I have found to change its position is to put this in the custom.css :

```
body #navigation {
position:absolute;
top:165px;
left: -50%;
right: 0;
margin: auto auto;
}
```

But that's not exactly centered ...

Can someone help me?

Comment: It doesn't work, the navigation bar is still in the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this css properties in your stylesheet:

```
#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center;
}
#navigation ul {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just copy and paste the above css code in your css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

well it depends how you have it set up with your entire code.. try this and see how it helps

```
#navigation {
  width:100%;
  left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:-601px;
```

Comment: It makes it move but how I can put it exactly in the center?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this properties to the following classes:

```
nav#navigation{
 width: 100%;
}
ul#main-nav{
 position: relative;
 right: 50%;
 transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

This code will center that menu.

Comment: I can't find any #main-nav in the style.css or layout.css, where is it?

Comment: It doesnt matter. Copy that in ...mystile/style.css. If it doesnt work you should add !important to all properties:
`nav#navigation{
 width: 100% !important;
}
ul#main-nav{
 position: relative !important;
 right: 50% !important;
 transform: translateX(50%) !important;
}`

Comment: Just tried and it's not centered at all. It just goes between the left and the middle